# SQLITE Perform Reverse full text search

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, sql-like

Imagine we have two tables, One named `tags` and one named `texts` as follows:

`tags` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 |
| 2 | T2 |
| 3 | T3 |
| 4 | T4 |

`Texts` table:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Text includes T2 |
| 2 | Text includes T4 |
| 3 | Text |
| 4 | Text includes T2 |

I want to search each `Text` and attach the tags from `Tags` table to each text. The output will be something like this:

| tagId | textId |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 |

I is like a loop over each text and then loop over each tag and check if that text includes that tag or not using `Like` statement. However this is not practical. The other method would be using `FTS` but I am not quite sure how to write its query since for example this query gives me only texts which have those tags

```
select *
  from texts_fts
 WHERE texts_fts MATCH ( select group_concat(tag, ' OR ')
                              from keywords
                             group by 'x' )
```

Is there any other approaches for getting this to work?
Thanks

Comment: This is a very simple requirement and the obvious solution is a join and the operator LIKE. Why do you consider it *not practical*?

Comment: @forpas May I ask how I can do it if I have a long table of `tags`? I think `LIKE` does not work on joins. Does it?

Comment: Of course it works. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a join and the operator `LIKE` in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT tg.id tagId, tx.id textId
FROM tags tg INNER JOIN texts tx
ON tx.text LIKE '%' || tg.name || '%'
```

Or with `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT tg.id tagId, tx.id textId
FROM tags tg INNER JOIN texts tx
ON INSTR(tx.text, tg.name)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e4d64fb986939d4d49b3a036291b57b8).